# Find the eigen value of a matrix without using the characteristic eqution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

For a 3x3 matrix, how to find the eigenvalues without using its characteristic equation, if one of the eigenvalues is given.
Suppose 2 is an eigenvalue of the matrix A, and find the others without using its characteristic equation
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}3&-1&1\\-1&5&-1\\1&-1&3\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Adding columns (or raws) gives 3, so 3 is an eigenvalue (with eigenvector $(1,1,1)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint- Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the other two eigenvalues. Then

- Sum of eigenvalues=trace(A)=(3+5+3)=11

$\implies \alpha+\beta=9$

- Ptoduct of eigenvalues=det(A)=$36$

$\implies \alpha\beta=18$